# clr-ui-dark.min.css file appears very large, even when bundles are optimized

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I'm just wondering if others see the same in their projects, or perhaps I've done something wrong, but it looks to me like the dark styling takes up about 1/3 (using webpack-bundle-analyzer) of the total size of my app.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the file to see which parts are larger than in other files?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack and Angular CLI don't optimize the CSS so its just a matter of how much code is being shipped compared with other parts of your application. If you really need to optimize your CSS, then the approach is you'd have to build it yourself and leave out the unnecessary parts, though this can be difficult and cause bugs if you don't keep it updated properly.

Comment: Hmm, okay thanks, regarding comparative sizes, I am just over the 2MB warning for Angular, which means the dark css stuff is getting close to 1MB